# JAVA - Failed to download json-lib

Tags: java, jmeter

Trying to install JMeter5.5 and followed this [article](https://sarkershantonu.github.io/2021/01/06/install-jmeter-plugins-cli/) , I'm with step 7 to download the plugins using cmdrunner-2.3.jar however I got issue on downloading json-lib. Please advise on how to resolve it.

This is the error message I'm gettiung when executed the step 7:

```
2023-03-04 02:02:43,339 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Downloading: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
2023-03-04 02:02:43,339 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Downloading json-lib...
2023-03-04 02:07:04,309 ERROR o.j.r.PluginManager: Failed to download json-lib
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.execute(JARSourceHTTP.java:499) ~[plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.JARSourceHTTP.getJAR(JARSourceHTTP.java:389) ~[plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.applyChanges(PluginManager.java:167) ~[plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.installAll(PluginManagerCMD.java:146) ~[plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:78) ~[plugins-manager.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62) ~[cmdrunner-2.3.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21) ~[cmdrunner-2.3.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:117) ~[cmdrunner-2.3.jar:?]
```

Comment: `search.maven.org` no longer responds to plaintext HTTP requests; use `https`.

Comment: @Joe, the `cmdrunner` is requesting the url, or the repo (`org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD`).

Comment: I see the files from my browser when trying to access HTTPS = https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/ , while getting error 501 response from HTTP = http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/ . May I ask on from which section can I correct this?

Comment: @Legon, it appears they know of this issue, but [haven't fixed it.](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/pull/572)

Comment: @l'L'l  - thanks for sharing this, seems like is already a known issue from developers side. I'll track their progress too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the url it's trying to download from is timing out.

```
2023-03-04 02:02:43,339 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Downloading: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
...
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

pinging `search.maven.org` comes back with:

```
% ping search.maven.org -c 5
PING search-maven-org-prod-env.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com (34.195.195.141): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

--- search-maven-org-prod-env.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Obviously the url mentioned in step 7 is no longer valid, or it's temporarily down. Whatever the case, that's the problem, and you'll need to find an alternate download url for the file `json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar`.

Maybe try these steps instead (starting from step #2):

2. `curl -O https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.5.zip`
3. `tar -xvf apache-jmeter-5.5.tgz`
4. `rm -rf apache-jmeter-5.5/docs apache-jmeter-5.5/printable_docs`
5. `cd apache-jmeter-5.5/lib ; curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar`
6. `cd ext/ ; curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/jmeter-plugins-manager/1.8/jmeter-plugins-manager-1.8.jar`
7. `cd .. ; java -jar cmdrunner-2.3.jar --tool org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD install-all-except jpgc-hadoop,jpgc-oauth,ulp-jmeter-autocorrelator-plugin,ulp-jmeter-videostreaming-plugin,ulp-jmeter-gwt-plugin,tilln-iso8583`
8. `cd apache-jmeter-5.5/bin ; ./jmeter.sh --version`
9. `cp -r apache-jmeter-5.5 /opt/`
10. `nano .profile`

    Add Jmeter Home variable at the end of the line

    `JMETER_HOME="/opt/apache-jmeter-5.5"`

    Modify PATH variable at the end of the line

    `PATH="$JMETER_HOME/bin:$PATH"`

    Reload your bash profile

    `source ~/.profile`

The steps above simply follow those of article you linked, although swapping the older version of the managers and plug-in with the newest. It could simply be that url (mentioned above) `cmdrunner` is trying to install the `json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar` from is down.

Comment: is it the plugins manager that needs to be modified or the cmdrunner? sorry I'm just new to this

Comment: @Lagot: No, it's the tutorial that needs fixed. They are telling you to download a file from a url that times out or doesn't exist.

Comment: @Lagot: I edited my answer to include the steps with updated versions of what was attempting to be installed, so give it a try.

Comment: @Il'L'l - tried your steps, still it get stuck on downloading the file from non-https maven url

Comment: In your configuration files look for `jmeter.json`. You can do `find . -name 'jmeter.json' -exec echo {} \';` to search recursively. Once you find it look at the `json` for any `http://` and try changing it to `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to download the json-lib now, it appears that it still pulls from via http and able to get the file. Seems like changes under this [discussion](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/pull/572) fixed the issue.

```
2023-03-06 00:25:39,507 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Downloading: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
2023-03-06 00:25:39,507 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Downloading json-lib...
023-03-06 00:25:40,548 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Downloaded json-lib...
```